# Unsatisfiable dependency on Apache Spark: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: libsvm/svm_print_interface

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I get the error in the title,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: libsvm/svm_print_interface
```

from this line of code

```
    val model = new LibSVM()
```

when I try to use the LibSVM library on a spark cluster. The strange thing is that when I run the code locally, without Spark, it works fine.

build.sbt local dependencies

```
"nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka" % "weka-stable" % "3.8.1",
"nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka" % "LibSVM" % "1.0.10",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

spark dependencies

```
17/04/23 00:54:23 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR /.../.ivy2/cache/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/jars/weka-stable-3.8.1.jar at spark://192.168.0.104:44703/jars/weka-stable-3.8.1.jar with timestamp 1492901663416
17/04/23 00:54:23 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR /.../.ivy2/cache/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/LibSVM/jars/LibSVM-1.0.10.jar at spark://192.168.0.104:44703/jars/LibSVM-1.0.10.jar with timestamp 1492901663418
17/04/23 00:54:23 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR /.../target/scala-2.11/cmaes_spark_2.11-0.1.jar at spark://192.168.0.104:44703/jars/cmaes_spark_2.11-0.1.jar with timestamp 1492901663468
```

Do you have any suggestions that could lead to solving this issue?

Comment: How did you deploy the code and these dependencies?

Comment: You to get the dependencies on the nodes, you'd have to build a fat jar. Have a look at the assembly plugin for sbt.

Comment: Well, that's how I would do it, but @Grant doesn't *have* to do that to get the dependencies on the runtime classpath. That's why I inquired about the method.

Comment: True, there are other ways.

Comment: Thank you both very much! I had used `sc.addJar("/.../LibSVM-1.0.10.jar")` - both inside the spark action and on master. I tried the assembly plugin as you suggested and it works now.